# nextjs with custom express server not redirecting url's on production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, vercel

I have a NextJS project hosted on Vercel
I have added server.js file to use custom express server that will 301 redirect some urls
when I run it locally the re-directions work but when I push the code to production on Vercel the re-directions doesn't work

This is the server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express()
    server.use(bodyParser.json())

    //Redirect to main page
    server.get(
        [
            '/product-tag/885-m2/?orderby=menu_order',
            '/product-tag/885-m2/?orderby=price',
            '/cutter/mwhzt-zvvit/mwhzt-zvvit-2.html?___store=default&___from_store=english',
            '/sales/guest/form/'
        ]
        , (req, res) => {
            res.redirect(301, '/')
        })

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    })

    server.listen(3000, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('> Read on http://localhost:3000')
    })
})
```

and this is my package.json scripts section:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node --inspect server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The urls generally do not contain the query params i.e the part after "?" in the request. Try this instead.

```js
    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        const redirectUrls = [
            '/product-tag/885-m2/?orderby=menu_order',
            '/product-tag/885-m2/?orderby=price',
            '/cutter/mwhzt-zvvit/mwhzt-zvvit-2.html?___store=default&___from_store=english',
            '/sales/guest/form/'
        ]; 
        if (redirectUrls.includes(req.url)) {
          res.redirect(301, '/');
        }
        next();
    })
```

Also make sure you write it above

```js
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  return handle(req, res)
})
```

otherwise, the code will never run.

Comment: I can try your solution, thank you, But I don't think thats it issue because for example when I run the site locally the redirect work from "http://localhost:3000/sales/guest/form/" to "http://localhost:3000/". But it doesn't work on production after I push the code to nextjs Vercel

Comment: I tried your code, the re direct doesn't work on production

Comment: having the same issue, did anyone find the solution to this problem?